# Как сделать hover effect с иконкой поверх картинки?

Tags: html, css, icon, градиент

Мне необходимо с помощью `css` и его `:hover` наложить градиент и `icon` поверх картинки.
Выглядеть это должно примерно вот [так](https://yadi.sk/i/aHdv0Qar3Vhnph), у меня же получается это только вот так:

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://krolik74.kpeatop.com/hosting.png) no-repeat;
  width: 588px;
}

.test:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 188, 240, 0.7) 0%, rgba(5, 42, 64, 0.7) 100%), url(http://krolik74.kpeatop.com/hosting.png) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

</div>
```

Подскажите как сделать пожалуйста. И еще возможно есть картинки вставлять через html, а не через css?

Comment: Такой вариант пробовали `<img src="путь-к-файлу" alt="описание">`

Comment: Да, конечно. Этот вопрос актуален, только если найдется ответ на вопрос выше. Как вставить картинки в html я знаю:)

Comment: Нашёлся ответ:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```css
.test {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://krolik74.kpeatop.com/hosting.png) no-repeat;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.testHover {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 188, 240, 0.7) 0%, rgba(5, 42, 64, 0.7) 100%), url(http://krolik74.kpeatop.com/hosting.png) no-repeat;
}
.test:hover .testHover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="test">
    <div class='testHover'>
      <i class="fas fa-link"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

**P.S** для иконки я использовал `font-awesome` вот линк на него:

> [Ccылка](https://fontawesome.com/get-started)

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря Zicrael (спасибо тебе) доработал так, как хотел. Чтобы картинки находились в html, а не css.

```
 <div class="container">
                <img src="http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/hosting.1526023725.png" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
                <div class="middle">
                    <div class="text">
                        <div class="union"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
}

.image {
  opacity: 1;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: .5s ease;
  backface-visibility: hidden;

}

.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
  /*opacity: 0.5; */

}

.container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 208px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 188, 240, 0.7) 0%, rgba(5, 42, 64, 0.7) 100%) no-repeat;
}

.union {
    background: url(http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Union.1526023689.png) center no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Так сказал бы,я бы редактировал как нужно:)